# Response.write and locale settings

Tags: .net, vb.net, locale

I am using VB .NET 4.0, ISS 7.0.
I wondered how can I set the default locale for all applications?

The problem is rising when I have a Response.Write(str) the numbers appear with ","(german notation) rather than "."(us notation).

From where .NET knows that he need to use the german locale?

In every my js script I have added

```
 Session.LCID = 3081;//  to fix the ,->.
```

but this is the brute force solution to fix the problem. Are there more elegant way to configure the server/.NET?

thanks
Arman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the locale in your app.config

Just add

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<globalization culture="CULTUREHERE, for example de-DE" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

Alternatively, you can change the culture your application thread uses at startup by setting the Current Culture:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE", false);
```

Comment: Thanks!! I am just using now:  <globalization
 fileEncoding="utf-8"
 requestEncoding="utf-8"
 responseEncoding="utf-8"
 culture="en-US"
 uiCulture="en-US"
    />

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `CultureInfo` in the [Numeric Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) options:

> 123.456 ("C", fr-FR) -> 123,46 €

for example